# DreamWeaver : css with less... access denied

Tags: css, macos, less, dreamweaver

While the less app is opened, I can't save my .less files with DreamWeaver CS6.
I get a popup with the message below :

http://nsa32.casimages.com/img/2013/01/31/130131035942448479.png

*The access to www[...]css/style.less has been denied.

I tried editing the file with vim, and everything went well.

Has someone already had this error ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to have LESS.app compile from an external server (say you're connected to your web server).

Unfortunately, LESS doesn't have access to edit the files (execute on the server), and therefore cannot compile the files into CSS.

I ran into the same problem, and tested it out with a `.less` file on my Desktop, and it compiled just fine.

I have no access to try and give execute, so I'm not entirely sure if more permissions would work (it may be a limitation of LESS.app).

Comment: For me this answer was useful and was pretty close to solving my issue and my issue went along these lines. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.  I was getting this when creating a launchd configuration file which watched my .less file which then ran a shell script to compile the .less file to .css. A great solution since for me the Dreamweaver CC Less Compiler from DMXzone would not work at all in DWCC.  In DWCS6 it worked great.  In any case, the way I fixed this issue was to open the .less file that will not save in Dreamweaver, do a Save As, and rename the file. Then delete the file that would not save, then from the Saved As Copy, do another Save As back to the original file name.  This fixed the issue for me and I hope it helps someone else. Its an awful solution. I tried everything from changing permissions to clearing my launchd config etc...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to go to:

> Site setup > CSS Preprocessors > General

Then uncheck 'Enable Auto Compilation On File Save'

It did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Edit -> Preferences`.

Under the `Category` tag, select `File Types / Editor` and add the `.less` extension (or anything else).